# Does single tile, single date of Sentinel-2 data require BRDF?

Tags: tiles, sentinel-2, reflectance

I have a single tile of Sentinel-2 Level-2A data from a single date of acquisition.

Does this require bidirectional reflectance distribution function (BRDF), or are the angles consistent enough during this data acquisition that BRDF would be negligible?